# Do two Lie brackets differ by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I'm thinking about the following seemingly simple problem. Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, and $[\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_1$,
$[\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_2$ be two distinct Lie brackets on $V$.

> Is there always some $A \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ such that either
> $A [\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_1 = [\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_2$ or
> $A [\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_2 = [\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_1$?

For example, if $[\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_1$ is arbitrary and
$[\,\cdot\,, \cdot\,]_2$ is trivial (always $0$), then we can simply take the $0$ matrix $A$ and obtain the result. Now of course if the two brackets are swapped in position than this no longer holds, so the order matters.

This seems natural to me, but I do not know how to approach this problem, other than trying to find counterexamples with low dimensional Lie algebras. But I am struggling there too. Any help would be appreciated, and if there is already known results about this (a proof or a counterexample) I would greatly appreciate a reference as well.

Comment: You're probably familiar with the fact that the vector (cross) product endows $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a real Lie algebra structure called $\mathfrak{so}(3, \mathbb{R})$. But there's another Lie bracket on $\mathbb{R}^3$ coming from choosing a basis for the $2 \times 2$ trace $0$ matrices $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$. Have a look [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Table_of_Lie_groups#/Real_Lie_algebras).

Comment: @SammyBlack would these two provide a counterexample?

Comment: Yes. This seems like a pretty difficult exercise unless you've seen some of these standard examples of Lie algebras. Even then, you have to figure out how to rule out an isomorphism between them. The trick there is to find a property that is preserved under such a map, and that only one of the Lie algebras satisfies.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I'm not even sure if that is the question. I read it as asking whether there is an $A$ such that one of $A \cdot [x,y]_1 =[x,y]_2$ or $A \cdot [x,y]_2 =[x,y]_1$ holds for all $x,y$. For $A$ to be a LA homomorphism we would instead demand e.g. $A \cdot [x,y]_1 =[Ax,Ay]_2$. I cannot bring this together, and am not sure if we have a counterexample.

Comment: (Also note that even for two non-isomorphic simple LAs it is not true that there are "no homomorphisms whatsoever in either direction". There is always $0$. But as said, I think that's not even the question; and if it were, then $A=0$ would answer it in the positive.)

Comment: @Torsten: ah, you’re right of course, I misread and then didn’t think it through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the question seems a bit unclear. The way I interpret it is that (with your notation) you are asking if there is $A \in \mathrm{End}(V)$ such that at least one of either $A([x,y]_1)=[x,y]_2$, or $A([x,y]_2)=[x,y]_1$, holds for all $x,y \in V$.

No, as per the following counterexample:

On $\mathbb R^3$ with standard basis $e_1,e_2, e_3$, define a Lie bracket $[ \cdot, \cdot]_1$ by $[e_1,e_2]_1 = -[e_2,e_1]_1 = e_1$, all other $[e_i, e_j]_1 =0$. Define a second Lie bracket via $[e_2,e_3]_2= - [e_3,e_2]_2 = e_2$, all other $[e_i, e_j]_2=0$.

There cannot be an $A$ such that $A([e_2, e_3]_1) = [e_2,e_3]_2$ because the LHS is $0$ and the RHS is not. But neither can there be an $A$ such that $A([e_1,e_2]_2)=[e_1, e_2]_1$ because the LHS is $0$ and the RHS is not.

Note that this is the case even though the two Lie algebras are actually isomorphic; they both are of the form $\mathbb R \oplus S$ where $\mathbb R$ is the one-dimensional abelian and $S$ is the two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra.

---

Here is how I came up with this counterexample. The question can be reformulated as: If $f: V \otimes V \rightarrow V$ is the linear map induced by the first Lie bracket, and $g: V\otimes V \rightarrow V$ the one induced by the second Lie bracket, is there a linear map $A : V \rightarrow V$ in either direction which makes the obvious triangular diagram commute? And it's clear there cannot be one as soon as the kernels of $f$ and $g$ are not contained in one another, one way or the other. Admittedly, since $f$ and $g$, coming from Lie brackets, cannot just be *any* linear maps, something like this cannot be constructed for $\dim(V) \le 2$, but for $\dim(V)=3$, the above example offered itself.

Comment: This is indeed the correct interpretation for my question. Now it seems there is a natural follow up: When can there exist such an $A$ between two isomorphic Lie algebras? Is it as you mention when the kernels are equal to each other (or one contained in the other)? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think so: One can make the diagram commute if and only if, for those maps induced on the tensor product by the respective brackets, one of the kernels is contained in the other. (And the map goes "from smaller to bigger kernel".) This includes your example of one of the Lie brackets being zero, i.e. the kernel is all. --- Whether that is the case would have to be computed for the Lie brackets given. Not sure if it would be strongly related to whether the Lie brackets give out isomorphic Lie algebras or not.